# Combine data from two datasources into a single table

Tags: google-app-maker

I have two datasets:

1. **Dataset 1** - Records the details of a store visit. Merchandiser name, location, date & a relation to SKU (Dataset 2)
2. **Dataset 2** - This is the SKU data, where the stock levels for each sku are input as a new record, each associated to a visit from Dataset 1.

I have two issues:

1. I want to combine this data into a single table. I want to show each SKU record, with additional columns for the visit information (such as the location & date). How do I do this.
2. How do I combine this data for use elsewhere, such as google data studio. Essentially I want to be able to see an SKU's stock-level's history, or the date it was last updated.

Comment: Read the documentation for calculated models. That should give you what you need. https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated

Comment: Thank you for this. My problem with using scripts, is I do not know where to put them. Where would I put a script like the one in the documentation?

Also, I'm still trying to wrap my head around the scripting itself, so I am not sure what I would need to write to make this happen :S

Comment: I see your point. I have a lot of work to do right now but if no one provides an example in 5-6 hours. I'll post an answer with a detailed example.

Comment: Thank you very much @morfinismo I really appreciate it. I have a basic understanding of scripting and js, but I’m struggling as to how to apply it within the context of google apps maker. Particularly with regards to WHERE to put scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Calculated Data Source. You can refer [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/calculated-model/) sample.

On a high Level

1. Add data source in Appmaker.
2. Select Calculated, provide Name and Create the data source.

Once your Calculated Model is in place. Add fields as per need basis. e.g. If you want to store Sum of two fields, create one Integer field in Calculated Model. Here's how your calculated data model will look like.

[image: Sample]

Now go to Second Tab which is "Datasources". Click on the Data Model name there. You should see an option to write server side script.[image: Sample2]

Here you should write your logic for combining your data sources. I can provide you one sample to achieve this.

```
//server script
var calculatedModelRecords = [];
var recordsByStatus = {};
var allRecord = app.models.Request.newQuery().run(); //your existing data source.


for (var i = 0; i < allRecord.length; i++) {
     var record = allRecord[i];
    var draftRecord = app.models.TAT.newRecord(); //new data source 
    draftRecord.CreatedOn = record.CreatedOn;
    draftRecord.DocumentName = record.DocumentName;
    draftRecord.DueDate = record.DueDate;
    draftRecord.DaysPerStage = record.DaysPerStage;  
    draftRecord.Status = record.Status;  
  calculatedModelRecords.push(draftRecord);    
}

return calculatedModelRecords;
```

Comment: What If I want to add filters to columns (Like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo-5AE5P1HA)- I cannot do that on a table made from a calculated model.