# Appmaker data in column and row

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm an IT-guy at a school and I try to make some apps for them.
I'm struggling with this problem:

I have two datasources:

- one with all the students
- one with a list of educational needs

There is a relation between these two.

I made a page where I can select the educational needs for every student.

- So `student1` has edu `need 1` and edu `need 3`
- `Student2` has edu `need 2` and edu `need 3`

The next step is to get a table like this:

```
educational need     student1     student 2
need 1                  x
need 2                               x
need 3                  x            x
```

Someone? It would be a great help!

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018281/combine-data-from-two-datasources-into-a-single-table). You need calculated data source in order to achieve table like this

Comment: Not easy for me, but trying to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: How can I get my students as columns and needs as rows?

Comment: Start building calculated data model, instead of students as columns try having students as raws.

Comment: Start building calculated data model. Update me if you get stuck.

Comment: Tried to change the example script. I can't make it work. My scripting is not that good. Can I do this with relations between datasources?